# ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free without ever using free()?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am learning c++ right now, trying to solve [239. Sliding Window Maximum](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/) on Leetcode. Keep encountering `ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free` even though I have never used `free()` anywhere in my code. What could be the problem here?

My code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> maxSlidingWindow(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        if (k == 1) {
            return nums;
        }

        deque<int> q = {nums[k-1]};
        deque<int> qi = {k-1};
        for (int i = k-2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nums[i] > q.front()) {
                q.push_front(nums[i]);
                qi.push_front(i);
            }
        }
        vector<int> output = {q.front()};

        for (int i = k; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if (qi.front() < i - k + 1) {
                q.pop_front();
                qi.pop_front();
            }
            if (q.size() > 0) {
                while (q.back() <= nums[i]) {
                    q.pop_back();
                    qi.pop_back();
                }
            }
            q.push_back(nums[i]);
            qi.push_back(i);

            output.push_back(q.front());
        }
        return output;
    }
};
```

Full error message:

```
=================================================================
==23==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x6150000009fc at pc 0x000000356a92 bp 0x7ffd9138ecb0 sp 0x7ffd9138eca8
READ of size 4 at 0x6150000009fc thread T0
    #2 0x7f1796504082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
0x6150000009fc is located 508 bytes inside of 512-byte region [0x615000000800,0x615000000a00)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #4 0x7f1796504082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #4 0x7f1796504082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c2a7fff80e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a7fff80f0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff8100: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c2a7fff8110: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c2a7fff8120: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
=>0x0c2a7fff8130: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd[fd]
  0x0c2a7fff8140: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff8150: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c2a7fff8160: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c2a7fff8170: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c2a7fff8180: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==23==ABORTING
```

Comment: Use-after-free does not specifically refer to the `free()` function. It refers to using memory after it has been freed by *any* means. It could be use of a variable that's no longer in scope via a dangling pointer, use of memory that has been `free()`d, memory that has been `delete`d or `delete[]`, and more. Basically it just means you are accessing memory that you are no longer allowed to access. ASAN even tells you where it was allocated and where it was freed.

Comment: Are you completely 100% sure that `q` will never be empty when you try to access its front or back? Add checks for that.

Comment: Also, `q.size() > 0` is the same as `!q.empty()`. The latter is more explicit and immediately clear what it means.

Comment: Each `pop` might free memory the deque no longer needs. I would suspect the loop where the size is checked before the loop, but not during. The deque could become empty, and `q.back()` would then be in error.

Comment: `nums` is used without checking its size against `k`. Forget about *use-after-free*; you may just run into **index-out-of-bounds**. You didn't check your deques for emptiness before using accessors on them. You didn't check `k` and `nums`'s elements for valid positive/none-negative values. This snippet is a mine field; ready to blast every single moment.

Comment: @Red.Wave Well this code is written for OJ with very specific constraints: `-10^4 <= nums[i] <= 10^4` and `1 <= k <= nums.length <= 10^5`, so I don't think I need to check for those conditions. Still, I will keep your comment in mind in the future, thanks.

Comment: @haoyu none of these assumptions were stated in code - nore anywhere in the OP. Even with those constraints, a lot of places in the snippet seem tricky. *Pop*ing a deque with possible empty initial state and no proved *push* is a very probable outcome yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the error occurs when `q.back()` tries to access the last element of `q` when `q` is empty. After I changed this part of the code:

```
            if (q.size() > 0) {
                while (q.back() <= nums[i]) {
                    q.pop_back();
                    qi.pop_back();
                }
            }
```

to this:

```
            while (!q.empty()) {
                if (q.back() <= nums[i]) {
                    q.pop_back();
                    qi.pop_back();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

the problem is resolved.